# ObservableMap bound to TableView not updating new values

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I have an `ObservableMap` that I want to bind to a tableview, to show some of the properties that map's values have, but new values on the map are not shown. Searching on SO and googling I found mostly the same code but with no solution.

Heres is a SSCCE that explain the problem, with the only 'solution' I found: create a new `ObservableList` with the values of the map and set it to the table **each time** the map changes, which is not a great solution.

```
public class MapTableBindTest extends Application {

    int personIDCounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        personIDCounter = 0;
        // Map - TableView binding
        ObservableMap<Integer, Person> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

        Person first = new Person("First", "Person");   // this person is mapped before the bind to the table
        map.put(first.getID(), first);                  // and because that, is shown on it

        ObservableList<Map.Entry<Integer, Person>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.entrySet());
        TableView<Map.Entry<Integer, Person>> table = new TableView<>(list);

        Person second = new Person("Second", "Person"); // once the bind has been setted no new items
        map.put(second.getID(), second);                // are shown on the table. Same case when added in the UI

        // Columns
        TableColumn<Map.Entry<Integer, Person>, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().getName());
        TableColumn<Map.Entry<Integer, Person>, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Surname");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().getSurname());
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, lastNameCol);

        // View
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TextField nameField = new TextField();
        TextField lastNameField = new TextField();
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            Person newP = new Person(nameField.getText(), lastNameField.getText());
            map.put(newP.getID(), newP);    // new items are not populated in the table...
            nameField.clear();
            lastNameField.clear();
            //                      ... unless a new observable list is created and setted to the table
            ObservableList<Map.Entry<Integer, Person>> auxiliarList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.entrySet());
            table.setItems(auxiliarList);
            //                      commenting this two lines result with no updates shown in the table
        });
        HBox TextHB = new HBox(nameField, lastNameField, addButton);
        root.setTop(TextHB);
        root.setCenter(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Sample class with some properties
    class Person {

        private int id;
        private StringProperty name, surname;

        public Person(String name, String surname) {
            id = personIDCounter++;
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.surname = new SimpleStringProperty(surname);
        }

        public int getID() {
            return id;
        }

        public StringProperty getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }
    }
}
```

May be something is wrong with the binding between the `entryset()` of the map to the `ObservableList`. The javadoc says about `entrySet()` of an `ObservableMap`:

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. **The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.** (...)

Which is not clearly happening, otherwise the TableView would be updated with the changes.

**Solution** (thanks to James_D):
This listener on the `ObservableMap` adds/remove the values changes in the `ObservableList` and therefore shown in the table.

```
map.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer, ? extends Person> c) -> {
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            Person added = c.getValueAdded();
            list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Person>(added.getID(), added));
        } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
            Person removed = c.getValueRemoved();
            list.remove(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Person>(removed.getID(), removed));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map is changing when you add items to it, and the set returned by `entrySet()` also changes. However, that set is not an observable set, so there is no way the `ObservableList` can possibly "see" any changes that occur to it.

Instead, you need to wire the list to the map directly. You can do this simply by making the table view a `TableView<Person>` and then registering a listener with the map:

```
map.addListener((Change<? extends Integer, ? extends Person> c) -> {
    if (c.wasAdded()) {
        list.add(c.getValueAdded());
    } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
        list.remove(c.getValueRemoved());
    }
});
```

Here's the complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MapTableBindTest extends Application {

    int personIDCounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        personIDCounter = 0;
        // Map - TableView binding
        ObservableMap<Integer, Person> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

        Person first = new Person("First", "Person");   // this person is mapped before the bind to the table
        map.put(first.getID(), first);                  // and because that, is shown on it

        ObservableList<Person> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.values());
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(list);

        map.addListener((Change<? extends Integer, ? extends Person> c) -> {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                list.add(c.getValueAdded());
            } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                list.remove(c.getValueRemoved());
            }
        });

        Person second = new Person("Second", "Person"); // once the bind has been setted no new items
        map.put(second.getID(), second);                // are shown on the table. Same case when added in the UI

        // Columns
        TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getName());
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Surname");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getSurname());
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, lastNameCol);

        // View
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TextField nameField = new TextField();
        TextField lastNameField = new TextField();
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            Person newP = new Person(nameField.getText(), lastNameField.getText());
            map.put(newP.getID(), newP);    // new items are not populated in the table...
            nameField.clear();
            lastNameField.clear();
        });
        HBox TextHB = new HBox(nameField, lastNameField, addButton);
        root.setTop(TextHB);
        root.setCenter(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Sample class with some properties
    class Person {

        private int id;
        private StringProperty name, surname;

        public Person(String name, String surname) {
            id = personIDCounter++;
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.surname = new SimpleStringProperty(surname);
        }

        public int getID() {
            return id;
        }

        public StringProperty getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying with the `Bindings` class, I supposed that maybe it would be some solution with predefined bindings-properties-listeners-things of javafx. I edited the question with the solution